# How to install and support SAP NW RFC SDK on Heroku for node.js project

Tags: node.js, saprfc

my project need SAP NW RFC SDK so how to install this framework on Heroku so that my API can work and extract data from a SAP system?

Comment: I guess you have already SAP NW RFC SDK. Could you explain what you tried and where you're stuck?

Comment: if we use sap-rfc then it required your OS to have some dll's related to sap so how can i do that in heroco as on my personal pc i have pasted in system32 folder: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rfc#prerequisites